# Build Access Control List (packet tracer)

Tags: list, acl, cisco

i'm triying to configure an access list, but it´s driving me mad.

[Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGvWF.png)
[Packet tracer file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apbz6idm0i869wk/ACL.pkt?dl=0)

Rules of ACL

Servers network

 No echo requests are allowed on the network by Users Network from Medellin and Customers Network from Cali.

 Telnet Access is allowed only for Administrator Network from Medellin and Bogota

Administrative network

 In this network is located administrative staff of the network from Bogota.

 This network has an HTTP server that is used only for internal users and server from Network Servers in Medellin

 This network can make echo requests anywhere.

 Eco request are only allowed to Servers and Administrative network in Medellin.

Financial Network

 Only users of the administrative network and servers located in Medellin can echo requests to the server.

 The network has a server with IP address = 172.16.0.10. Providing two services, HTTP, FTP and DHCP

 The Web service must be available to any user of the company and any Internet user.

 FTP service should only be available to users of the Administrative network  and servers network.

 The server may request echo requests anywhere other than the administrative network and servers Medellin.

Customer Network

 The customer network contains an HTTP server that is available to them and the administrative networks of Bogota and Medellin.

** Only users from administrative network can make echo requests.
 Only allowed access to internet and services from  Servers netowork located in medellin.** **I'm confused about this rules**

Users Network

 The network user only has permission to access the Internet through Bogota.

 Is blocked for echo requests to the Administrative Network from Bogota and Medellin, as the Medellin Network Servers

 Only allowed access to internet and services from  Servers netowork located in medellin and Administrative Network from Bogota

This is mi configuration for medellin Router

```
access-list 101
deny icmp 172.17.2.0 0.0.0.127 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 echo
deny icmp 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.63 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 echo
deny icmp host 172.16.0.10 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 echo
deny icmp host 172.16.0.10 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 echo
permit ip any any
access-list 102
deny icmp 172.17.2.0 0.0.0.127 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 echo
deny icmp 172.17.2.0 0.0.0.127 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 echo
deny icmp 172.17.2.0 0.0.0.127 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 echo
access-list 1
permit 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127
permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip access-group 101 out
interface FastEthernet1/1
ip access-group 102 out
line vty 0 4
access-class 1 in
password cisco
login
```

Bogota router

```
access list 101
permit tcp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 eq www
permit icmp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 echo
permit icmp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 echo
access list 102
permit icmp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 host 172.16.0.10 echo
permit icmp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 host 172.16.0.10 echo
permit tcp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 host 172.16.0.10 eq ftp
permit tcp 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.63 host 172.16.0.10 eq ftp
permit tcp any host 172.16.0.10 eq www
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip access-group 102 out
interface FastEthernet0/1
ip access-group 101 out
```

Cali router

```
access list 101
permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.63 eq www
permit tcp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.63 eq www
permit icmp 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.127 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.63 echo
permit icmp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.63 echo
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip access-group 101 out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See,
Packet Tracer is very unreliable. If you want to reliably emulate your configuration, use GNS3 emulator. Packet Tracer is buggy, majority of the features and detailed commands are straightaway missing, and those who are implemented are buggy and don't behave as expected.

I didn't read your full description and config, dont have time for that, but assuming your config is correct, use GNS3. That way you know surely if something is not working, then it's certainly not working.

Comment: Yes, i see that. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try Write this syntax :

```
Router(config)#access-list 101 permit tcp host 192.168.2.3 host 192.168.2.2 eq 80
Router(config)#access-list 101 permit tcp host 192.168.2.2 host 192.168.2.2 eq 80
```

and write your ip.

```
https://www.mediafire.com/file/iz8e5j0klw8ayn4/ACL_Test_With_TFTP_Server.rar/file
```

i was designed lab ACL and I wrote its own command with the explanation, i upload file in this link